# How to remove blockinput(1) effect by running blockinput(0) in another autoit script or exe file?

Tags: autoit

I am using these codes:

```
BlockInput(1)
Run(@DesktopDir & "\autoit\" & "mu.exe", "")
```

mu exe --> :

```
sleep(5000)
Blockinput(0)
```

blockinput(1) is working ok, but blockinput(0) is not effecting. how to remove effect of blockinput by running another autoit script or exe file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to run `BlockInput(0)` from the AutoIT script that has started it. You cannot run it from another script.

You need to change your script so the BlockInput is only called by one script.